# Tips for speed up development for Magento?

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I search a lot of magento performances articles about magento, I've tested `varnish`, `complier` and `memcached` ...etc. I no doubt with running those cache on Production servers. It runs like a rock, I am happy with that.

But I felt very painful on development magento modules. Whenever I edited lines of codes, I refresh the pages and see the update, it cost me 3~7 seconds on average. I am wondering if there is any order way to speed up on the development stage.

my development environment:

- MBA 10.9
- Vagrant 1.5 + Virtual Box + Ubuntu 12.04
- Nginx + PHP-FPM + PHP5.7
- disabled all caches while development <-- I known it.

Is there any tips?

Comment: you can use cloudflare application

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to use a debugger for PHP, so you do not need to refresh the page so often, saves a lot of time :-) I really regret to have lived in pain for many years ignoring the existence of PHP debuggers.

And for magento speed itself, do not deactivate all caches but do it as you go and as you need it. So you can let the configuration cache ON for most of the time except when you adjust some config XML of your module, then clear the cache once and let it ON.
The same for translation cache. Let them on except you tuned some translation files or web service configurations, clear them if you need it once.

EAV collection cache can stay ON as well if you actually do not work on models.

Only cache you have to disable permanently is block cache for the most dev work.

Last but not least, use APC opcode cache, but ENABLE **apc.stat=1**

And the last one: Use the best hardware you can afford :-) and consider doing the most work on a powerfull, dedicated desktop maschine instead of virtual one which you can use as backup dev environment if you need to be mobile.